# ¿Qué significa "sollado"?

Tags: definiciones, significado, colombia

Soy colombiano, y en Colombia se utiliza bastante "estar sollado", lo que quiere decir que uno está más o menos relajado, más o menos feliz.

Sin embargo eso es un significado ambiguo y tácito, me he dado cuenta de que no conozco exactamente lo que significa.

Pero, ¿qué significa exactamente? El DRAE no tiene una respuesta, dado que para ellos el sollado es una parte de un barco.

¿Alguien me podría indicar el origen de esta expresión y lo que en realidad significa?

Comment: El [fichero general de la RAE](http://web.frl.es/fichero.html) contiene 75 entradas de "sollado". No he leído todas, pero la mayor parte se corresponden con el uso de ["camarote inferior de un barco"](http://web.frl.es/FICHERO/FICHERO/LETRA_S/LETRA_S_PDF/SOLLADO/00000620.pdf). También he visto alguna entrada con el signigicado de ["loco"](http://web.frl.es/FICHERO/FICHERO/LETRA_S/LETRA_S_PDF/SOLLADO/00000617.pdf).

Comment: Nunca he escuchado ese término en Chile. Puede ser algo regional.

Comment: No sé que tendrá que ver con la palabra sollar, y desollar, pero probablemente venga por ahí el tema.

Comment: Por ser un 'Colombianismo' también puedes verlo escrito como "so**y**ado"  https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wikcionario:Colombianismos

Answer (score 12):

Para Colombia he encontrado este diccionario no oficial, pero que da una explicación que parece encajar con el significado que utilizas:

http://www.bogotalogo.com/wiki/index.php?title=Sollado

> Dícese de quien se halla sumido en un plácido sopor por causa del consumo de cierta sustancia estupefaciente.

En general, el diccionario de americanismos recoge:

> [**sollado, -a**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=ldT2RYE3cx0AzOhk9CJ)
>
> I.    1.  adj. Co:C,N, Ve. juv. Referido a persona, que no está en su sano juicio o tiene un comportamiento extravagante. pop.
>   2.  Ve. Referido a persona, que está bajo los efectos de la droga.
>
> II.   1.  adj. Co. juv. Referido a cosa, muy buena y fuera de lo común. pop.

Comment: Siempre he creído que _sollarse_, _sollado_ (y _solle_) viene del mundo de las drogas y ha pasado al lenguaje general para referirse a esa estimulación soporífica que causan ciertas situaciones o circunstancias. No tengo fuentes así que lo dejo como un comentario (y un voto).

Comment: Interesante... Mirando en el diccionario de la lengua española, http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=sollar, dice que "Despedir aire con violencia por la boca.", por lo que podría tener ese símil con quien está fumando (o fumó). Curiosamente, viene del latín "sufflare" que me recuerda el "sufflé" francés o el "soplar" castellano. Vaya, que el tema del viento y el soplar están presentes y el paso siguiente es imaginarse al fumador de sustancias estupefacientes.

Answer (score 6):

Añado esta referencia de acuerdo con lo indicado en [Juntemos en respuestas wiki las respuestas cortas específicas de regiones](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2483/1674). Edita libremente para incluir la versión de tu país o región.

---

### Costa Caribe

> alguien está loco en el buen sentido de la palabra, extrovertido sobre
>   todo.

### España > Canarias

- Rozadura

### Panamá

> indica que uno sufrió un raspadura en la piel que causa picazón y
>   enrojecimiento, por motivo del roce con la ropa, más común si se trata
>   de la entrepierna.

### Colombia

> - loco en el sentido de ser extrovertido: estar muy contento, ser muy enérgico.
>
> - estar fuera de sí
>
> - estar colocado, es decir, sumido en un plácido sopor por causa del
>   consumo de cierta sustancia estupefaciente.
>
> - Muy bonito, excelente. ej. Tu carro nuevo esta muy sollado (sollao es la pronunciación de la calle). 
>      Dado que se usa en un contexto muy de la calle se puede oír en expresiones como "¡Qué pinta tan sollada!" o "¡Qué solle de pinta!" que traducen al español como "Me gusta mucho la ropa que traes puesta".

### Venezuela

> estar loco

Comment: Sollado en la Costa Atlántica de Colombia, de donde creo que es originario este término, significa `loco`.

Comment: En Panamá se usa este término para indicar que uno sufrió un raspadura en la piel que causa picazón y enrojecimiento, por motivo del roce con la ropa, más común si se trata de la entrepierna.

Comment: Soy de Colombia, de la costa. Y pues acá se usa dependiendo del contexto. Cuando alguien esta fuera de sí, por ejemplo.

Comment: En España `sollado` significa que te has rozado algo. Por ejemplo en una caída con una bicicleta cuando te rozas también puedes decir: > me he **sollado** la rodilla.

Comment: En Venezuela generalmente se emplea para referirse a que la persona está loca.

Comment: En Canarias quiere decir "rozadura". Mis amigos colombianos aquí también lo utilizan para decir que están colocados (high) pero nunca lo han utilizado para decir que están felices.

Comment: En Colombia significa "loco" pero no como que te falta la razón. Por el contrario, significa estar muy contento, muy enérgico. Ser extrovertido.

Comment: no he oído nunca tal palabra en España.

Answer (score 4):

Soy originario de la costa Caribe, en esta región lo usamos cuando queremos decir que alguien está loco en el buen sentido de la palabra, extrovertido sobre todo.

Answer (score 3):

Sollado al definirlo criollamente en américa, es estar con los huevos o testículos irritados o pelados con un dolor insoportable que no se aguanta cuando caminas y los escrotos se te rozan con el movimiento de las piernas.

Sucede mucho al ponerse ropas apretadas, como cuando te queda la marca roja hundida en la carne por culpa del calzoncillo apretado.

También sucede la afección cuando guindan y rebenquean mucho los huevos en el órgano femenino de la mujer al momento del chiqui chiqui. Por eso mismo esa misma expresión y los mismo síntomas que el ejemplo anterior.

También otro ejemplo cuando estás con una chica encima sentada, y te pones erecto por debajo de la ropa y de estar en esa fricción puede ocasionarse el efecto de estar sollado.

También se ha visto cuando las mujeres hacen ejercicios con licras muy pegados, el cuero de los labios de la vagina se irrita.

No crean que solamente da en casos de sexo. También los trabajadores de construcción han sufrido del problema.

Bueno, qué más puedo explicar si lo dije todo.

Answer (score 2):

A mi modo de ver, sollado derivó de la palabra "solle". Entiendo que la primera denota cierto grado de locura (sin llegar a la insanidad mental). También es posible aplicarla a aquella persona que es demasiado extrovertida. Te "posteo" un artículo publicado en el periódico "El universal" de Cartagena, titulado ["Evolución solle"](http://www.eluniversal.com.co/suplementos/dominical/evolucion-solle-134776). Saludos.

> Cada vez que abordo este tema, explico qué era ser “solle” en Cartagena en los años setenta y ochenta. Se trata de un calificativo, con que la sociedad de entonces, nominó a los jóvenes aficionados a la “música americana”, es decir, toda la música rock, pop,  disco, Groove, funk, dance, entre muchos otros ritmos que siguieron como el tecno, el house y el electro house. “Solle” de sollado, de arrebatado en su forma de vestir, de bailar, de actuar la música que circulaba por la vieja emisora La Voz de la Victoria. No había banda FM en la radio, ni existían computadores, ni celulares, ni tabletas. No había internet y el mundo digital sólo aparecía en el cine de ciencia ficción, sugerido por un panel de foquitos parpadeantes, como en La Guerra de las Galaxias (1978).
>
> Se me antoja curioso, darme cuenta de cómo los jóvenes de la época teníamos una visión optimista del futuro. Sentíamos muy distante el año 2000 y lo imaginábamos como una gran fiesta disco, donde todo el mundo lucía trajes espaciales brillantes. Y a ese referente corresponde la imagen del dúo francés Daft Punk y su éxito musical Get Lucky. Más curioso se me antoja ver cómo las generaciones actuales, para asumir el futuro, regresaron al pasado. Regresaron al disco y al Groove. Y, como resultado, a los ojos de los “solles cartageneros, se trata de una evolución. Una evolución “solle”. Tuvieron que recurrir a un artista genial, como lo es Nile Rodgers: músico negro nacido en Nueva York, en 1952. En picós de Cartagena sonaron los éxitos del negro Rodgers, cuando formaba parte del grupo Chic y tuvieron éxitos como Everybody dance, Le Freak y Good Times. Muy destacable esta última canción, porque es la base de la invención del hip – hop con la canción Rapper’s Delight del grupo Sugarhill Gang, una pieza muy picotera para entonces. Rodgers ha sigo productor de artistas como Diana Ross, con éxitos como Upside Down y I’m coming out. Produjo también para el inglés David Bowie, Let’s Dance; para Madonna, Like a Virgen; para Duran Duran, The Reflex, Notorious y The Wild Boys.
>
> Pueden ver a Nile Rodgers vestido de traje entero blanco, tocando guitarra y cantando Le Freak en este video: http://31.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_ma5xrf2MMO1rewq09o1_500.gif
>
> La autenticidad en la obra de este artista está en su virtuosismo con la guitarra de acompañamiento. Rodgers nos explica el devenir de su técnica musical, a lo largo de cuarenta años de producción, en el documental Random Acces Memories: The Collaborators, el cual, pueden ver aquí: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=da_Yp9BOCaI. Toda evolución implica adaptaciones a cambios que se dan en el entorno. Es claro que la moda “solle” corresponde a un sentimiento concreto que apareció en un momento dado en Cartagena, respecto a una generación. Una buena forma de establecer el arco evolutivo de la manifestación “solle” está en comparar las fiestas de entonces, con las de ahora. Fiestas “solle”, por supuesto, como las que hacía Ventura Julio en Manga, en el patio de su casa. Para la época, no había sillas rimax. Había puro banquillo. Un escenario donde la habilidad para el baile y la actuación de la ropa y la moda eran medulares para vivir la noche. Sábado por la noche. El rito festivo de hoy es otro, porque los tiempos cambian; sin embargo, obras musicales como la de Nile Gregory Rodgers son insuperables, inmortales; aunque la palabra “solle” suene extraña a la generación actual; aunque muchos de nosotros escondan las fotos de la época. Y aunque se burlen de uno.

Answer (score 2):

La expresión sollado puede tener una connotación positiva o negativa depende del contexto.
Si estoy en un contexto de alegría y diversión estar sollado puede significar que estoy muy feliz y soy un derroche de alegría.

Si es en un contexto de enojo y frustración estar sollado puede significar que estoy muy enojado y no mido mis palabras y actos.

Existe gente que utiliza esta expresión para significar "el estar bajo los efectos de las drogas" pero eso es dentro de un ámbito excepcional.

Answer (score 1):

> Sollar. (Del lat. sufflāre).
>
> 1. tr. ant. Despedir aire con violencia por la boca.
> 2. tr. ant. Arrojar aire por medio de fuelles u otros artificios.

Es posible que sea lo que haces cuando te entra un sopor.

> sopor. (Del lat. sopor, -ōris).
>
> 1. m. Adormecimiento, somnolencia.
> 2. m. Med. Modorra morbosa persistente.

De aquí estar sollado.

Rasparse la piel, figuradamente, es desollarse.

> desollar. (Del lat. vulg. *exfollāre, der. del lat. follis, fuelle, bolsa de cuero).
>
> 1. tr. Quitar la piel del cuerpo o de alguno de sus miembros. U. t. c. prnl.
> 2. tr. Causar a alguien grave daño en su persona, honra o hacienda.

Comment: Buena respuesta. +1.  Deberias citar la fuente.

Answer (score 0):

In castillian, "sollado" is used as an adjective or also a verb to remark that someone has cut all his/her hair to the point of having no hair. It is also related to the term "sin cabeza” ( without head, beheaded). It actually means without head, but used commonly to say the person shaved is head. "Olla" is a receptacle kitchen tool to boil water, but used commonly in spain to refer to the head. So the "s" part is used as for "without", "cut off". Olla is the head and ado is the verb conjugation. "Lo han sollado".

Note that this word is not used on polite speaking or writing and you would have difficulty finding someone actually saying it on a city. This word would be more proper on rural areas.

Comment: En mi región (Alicante) también se usa "chollar" para esta misma definición de rasurarse el pelo (tampoco reconocido por DRAE).

Comment: Parece que chollado es la version alicantina :)